# Get current relative URL including unescaped query strings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I request a URL like: `/Offers/Create?Provider=Nicholas Associates&ProviderID=2&PlacementModal=1`

In this requested View, is a form. What I want to do is make sure that my Form action value takes the URL of the view it's being displayed on including the passed params.

So for example:

`<form action="/Offers/Create?Provider=Nicholas Associates&ProviderID=2&PlacementModal=1">`

I have tried:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Create" + Request.QueryString, "Manage", FormMethod.Post))`

But it's outputting:

`<form action="Offers/Create%3fProvider%3dNicholas%2520Associates%26ProviderID%3d2%26PlacementModal%3d1%26_%3d1370350965816">`

How can I stop it escaping the URL?

Answer (score 0):

if your view correspond to your post action (mean the form's view action is `Manage/Create` and your post action is `Manage/Create` , you can just do

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

The querystring will be taken.

Now, if you want to post to another action, you can do

```
@{ var queryStringDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => (object) Request.QueryString[key])); }

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Offers",queryStringDictionary, FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Tried that. The action became: `<form action="/Offers/Create?Count=4&amp;Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&amp;Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D">`

Comment: @Cameron I inverted ActionName and ControllerName in my answer, Maybe Try edit...